# Controlling when font face downloads the font

Tags: javascript, css

From my understanding font-face downloads the font straight away and then whenever you use the font it just applies it. My "issue" is that most computers have Century Gothic installed, so I don't want to be wasting time downloading a font (Which isn't actually Century Gothic it's an alternative that looks similar) if they already have it.

My question is, is it possible to control when @font-face downloads the actual font? Or does it only download it upon first use? The only option I can currently think of is to run a font test to see if Century Gothic is installed (Using JavaScript) then if it isn't inject a new style into the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a list of font-families, and the browser will use the first one that is available.
So if you set `font-family: 'Century Gothic', 'Your Other Font'`, then the other font will only be used if Century Gothic is not available.

**[This page](http://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/)** indicates that @font-face rules that are not actually used, will not be downloaded:

> Turns out if you use @font-face but don't ever apply that font-family, the font won't be downloaded. Pretty smart, browsers

Comment: Yes but the other font will still be downloaded. There is no reason to add that extra load time of downloading the extra font from my really bad servers if it's not going to use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use `local('Century Gothic')`? That would use the system's font, if it exists.

From http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/:

> The local values tell browsers to check for your typeface on a
>   visitor’s computer before attempting to load it from afar.

Thus, if the visitor's computer has the font, it will not be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jcsanyi for clearing up how the font face system works. With this in mind I was able to cook up a backup. I imported it with:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: CenturyGothicFallback;
    src: url('/Resources/Avant Garde Book BT.ttf');
}
```

then I applied it with:

```
font-family:Century Gothic,'Century Gothic',CenturyGothicFallback,Arial,sans-serif;
```

the font I used was: http://www.911fonts.com/font-download/download_AvantGardeBkBTBook_846.htm it looks almost exactly the same as Century Gothic.